# How to download to /res/raw using cordova-plugin-file

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using cordova to create a push application.  I'm trying to download a 20 second mp3 file and have that file play whenever the notification is received.  Android docs say it needs to be stored in `/res/raw` (see https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref).  I'm using a cordova file download plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file.  This plugin gives several locations preconfigured, but nowhere on the page does it even mention a /res folder.   If i try to download to `/res/raw` I get an error.

This is made even worse by the fact that when I plug in my android device into my computer, I can't even see all the files on there.  I can't even see the APK for my app.

But back to the main question, using the cordova-plugin-file, how do I download a custom sound to `/res/raw` for use in a custom push notification?  I already can download the file just fine, I'm just having trouble specifying `/res/raw` as the endpoint.

Thanks!